# Check for conflicting events via a SELECT with datetime columns

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table called that's value is the `$instructor`:

| ID | start_date_time | end_date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-04-01 10:00:00 | 2018-04-02 14:00:00 |

The user in imputing a desired start and end date&time through a from to create a new event. I am seeking to check for any conflicting events via a `mysqli_num_rows` with a SELECT query as such :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$instructor` WHERE ('$FromDateTime' between start_date_time and end_date_time) OR ('$ToDateTime' between start_date_time and end_date_time) LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx4, $sql);
    $instructorcheck = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

I would then later on call the number of rows during an if() statement :

```
if ($instructorcheck > 0 || !$instructorcheck){....
```

I'm not sure if my formatting is incorrect but I keep on receiving a : `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result` error.

I'm not sure my statement is correct because what if a user requests and event with the start and end date&time being outside the existing events such as here : from *2018-04-01 09:00:00* to *2018-04-02 15:00:00*... Then neither the start or end times will fall `between` the *start_date_time* and  *end_date_time* in the table and the number of rows returned would be zero I presume... ?

Comment: Then `mysqli_query($db_conx4, $sql)` doesn't return a value of type `mysqli_result`. Did you check for errors (`mysqli_error_list()`)?

Comment: I have this in place : `if (!$sql) {print_r(mysqli_error_list($sql));}` yet I'm not getting any listing other than the parse error from above.. maybe my query for the listing of errors is invalid ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the `!$instructorcheck`located in your if statement. It shouldn't be used this way - your code should run now.